# Number of Integer Solutions for a Liner Equation

Tags: elementary-number-theory

The total number of integer pairs ($x$,$y$) satisfying the equation $x+y=xy$ is ....... $?$

Now I have solved this question by assuming the values of $x$ and then finding out the value of $y$ and I came with the solution set of $[(2,2),(0,0)]$  and I was not able to find any other solution set. Is my answer correct? Also in what way mathematically we can arrive at the correct answer without missing out any of the other possibilities. Please clarify!

Comment: $x+y=xy\implies x\mid y\land y\mid x\implies x=\pm y$

Comment: $x+y=xy$ is not a linear (much less, a *liner*) equation.